# ncftpls : Sort list by last modified date

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I'm using **ncftpls** on ubuntu to get FTP list files, is there a way to sort it by last modified date ?

```
ncftpls -l -u User -p Passwd ftp://my.ftp.server/*.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *might* be able to achieve this by telling `ncftpls` to send the "-t" option to the FTP server, *and* to use the `LIST` command (not `MLSD`), like so:

```
$ ncftpls -o useMLSD=0 -x "-lt" -u User -p Passwd ftp://my.ftp.server/*.txt
```

Note that this may not work; it depends on the remote FTP server implementing/handling the `-t` option for `LIST` commands.

Hope this helps!